# IBM AppCenter randomly showing installable apps on iOS7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've deployed an app on the IBM AppCenter.
Accessing the url http:///appcenterconsole/installers.html, after i insert the login (because the AppCenter is under security), from any devices different from iPhone running iOS7 , it works correctly.
On the latest Apple mobile operating system instead i saw a strange behavior. Randomly it shows the app to install, then i refresh and i cannot see anymore, then if i refresh again someteimes it shows sometimes it doesn't.
How can i debug this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, we edit the .js of the Application Center and forced a "refresh" of the list of applications so we avoid any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Worklight 5.0.6 or 6.0, you can use `http://myhost:myport/appcenterconsole/inst.html`. That is, instead of installers.html write inst.html. This page should show the apps as well, but in a simpler format. This page is less likely to run into browser incompatibilities since it does not use any JavaScript libraries. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hi, when i try to reach "inst.html" it shows a 404 error.
Is there something I have to add?
I'm using the AppCenter within the WL version 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You may try to enable cookie in your phone.